# How can I DRY up a series of upserts of the same fields from multiple tables?

Tags: postgresql, data-warehouse, etl

I have a bunch of tables that all have a `storenumber`, `extracteddate` and `extractedtime` column.

I'm doing ETL on these tables and I want to put the last extracted date and time for each store in a single table, with an additional column for the input table name.  So I've ended up repeating the same upsert a bunch of times and really the only thing that is different is the CTE that I am using for input:

```
with rows as (
  select distinct on(storenumber)
         storenumber, extracteddate, extractedtime
    from storefinancialdate
  )
  insert into star.stat_etl (storenumber, filename, last_extracted, last_loaded)
    select rows.storenumber,
           'storefinancialdate',
           (rows.extracteddate + rows.extractedtime::time),
           transaction_timestamp()
      from rows
    on conflict(storenumber, filename) do update
      set last_extracted = excluded.last_extracted,
          last_loaded    = excluded.last_loaded;

with rows as (
  select distinct on(storenumber)
         storenumber, extracteddate, extractedtime
    from storeproduct
)
insert into star.stat_etl (storenumber, filename, last_extracted, last_loaded)
  select rows.storenumber,
         'storeproduct',
         (rows.extracteddate + rows.extractedtime::time),
         transaction_timestamp()
    from rows
  on conflict(storenumber, filename) do update
    set last_extracted = excluded.last_extracted,
        last_loaded    = excluded.last_loaded;

-- repeat a bunch more times...
```

Is there some way that I can DRY this up?  I can't pass a CTE into a function, can I?

(I get that I could call a function on each record of each CTE, one at a time. That would make the code shorter but also much, much slower. So I don't want to do that.)

Comment: First, it's not clear what the "repeat a bunch of time" would be. Does only the table name change?  Second, the `distinct on ()` in the cte is not deterministic. There should be an `order by` there.

Comment: @ypercube -- re: distinct -- oops, well caught.  re: what changes -- see expanded example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `UNION` in the CTE. There is still some duplication of code but less than before:

```
with etl (storenumber, filename, last_extracted) as
(
    ( select distinct on (storenumber)
          storenumber, 
          'storefinancialdate',
          extracteddate + extractedtime::time 
      from storefinancialdate
      order by
          storenumber,
          extracteddate desc, extractedtime desc
    )
  union all
    ( select distinct on (storenumber)
          storenumber, 
          'storeproduct',
          extracteddate + extractedtime::time 
      from storeproduct
      order by
          storenumber,
          extracteddate desc, extractedtime desc
    )
  -- union all ...
)
insert into star.stat_etl 
    (storenumber, filename, last_extracted, last_loaded)
select 
    storenumber,
    filename,
    last_extracted,
    transaction_timestamp()
from etl
  on conflict (storenumber, filename) do update
    set last_extracted = excluded.last_extracted,
        last_loaded    = excluded.last_loaded ;
```